# Notation for fractions (divides by or over) in R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to place one word over another for a title. I mean literally over, not just a 'divides by' sign one value over another (or word) to save space. It is supposed to mean divides by and there needs to be a line.

I cannot find how to do this, can you help?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Study `help("plotmath")`.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911621/r-label-plots-with-fractions/15912603#15912603) post for an example.

Answer (score 20):

You can create fractions in a title with `frac()`:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point()
p + ggtitle(expression(paste("This is a fraction: ", frac(foo, bar))))
```

[image]

Note that the whole title must be put inside `expression()`. Alternatively, you can also use `over()` to do the same. The following example also shows that you can create other mathematical expressions in a similar fashion:

```
p + ggtitle(expression(paste("This is a fraction: ", over(3 * alpha, sum(b[i], i==1, N)))))
```

[image]

For more information, read `?plotmath`.